# How do I create a loop that prints each string with three or more letters and first and last letters are the same?

Tags: python

Sample data:

examples = ['abab', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bcb']

I need to write a loop that can go through and pick out the strings that have 3 or more letters and also the first and last letter are the same.

So far I can only get the 3 or more part
len(x) > 3 for x in examples[0:] but cannot figure out how to create the loop that will also pick the one with first and last letters the same.

The only question I'm asking is how to make it compare the first and last letters.  Not multiple questions here.

Comment: Reference the first character of the string.  Reference the last character.  Compare them.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please review your educational materials on string handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "need" the loop instead of list comprehension, you can simply iterate over the list and use the same conditions:

```
for word in examples:
    if len(word) >= 3 and word[0] == word[-1]:
        print(word)
        # or result.append(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

`results = [x for x in examples if len(x) >= 3 and x[0] == x[-1]]`

Comment: Thank you and this works but I need it to be a loop.

Comment: That is a loop. It has the `for` loop statement. It is list comprehension

Comment: @Barb it's most likely a homework question that requires answers to begin with `for x in examples` or something fixed like that for which I can't be bothered to spoonfeed

Comment: Guys I'm just trying to learn.  Thank you for explaining that @Barb.  I spent a ton of time to get to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way:

```
examples = ['abab', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bcb']

output_list = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) >=3 and x[0] == x[-1], examples))

print(output_list)
# ['abab', 'bcb']
```

With loop:

```
output_list = list()
for x in examples:
    if len(x) >= 3 and x[0] == x[-1]:
        output_list.append(x)

print(output_list)
# ['abab', 'bcb']
```

Comment: Thank you and this works but I need it to be a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've been trying to understand the lambda x function.  The literature just goes beyond me.  Python is much harder than R to me.